# How to check if string follows the correct pattern / format given

Tags: php, regex

I have string which has this following patterns:

1. ?language=english&module=login
2. ?language=english&module=main&menu=dashboard
3. ?language=english&module=main&menu=dashboard&action=view

and im using this regex

```
preg_match("[^?]+(=[^&]+){*}", $url )
```

but it's not working. How can I check if the string follows those 3 patterns or more.

?word=word&word=word&word=word

Comment: One thing is certain: you need to add regex delimiters. Also, `{*}` is not a quantifier, what did you want to express with it? I think you wanted to get something like [`'~^\?[^&]+(?:&[^&]+)*$~'`](https://regex101.com/r/oAtF5S/1)

Comment: Use `parse_str` instead

Comment: already solved. I used Wiktor's regex. "/^\?[^&\n]+(?:&[^&\n]+)*$/" its a very useful site for regex.

Comment: You could let me know with `@`+username that my suggestion works. I will post then.

Comment: I added an answer with explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to add regex delimiters as PHP `preg_` functions require them for the regex to work.

Also, `{*}` is not a quantifier, it matches 0+ `{` symbols and then a literal `}`.

You may use

```
'~^\?[^&]+(?:&[^&]+)*$~'
```

See  the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oAtF5S/1).

- `^` - start of string
- `\?` - a literal `?`
- `[^&]+` - 1 or more symbols other than `&`
- `(?:&[^&]+)*` - zero or more sequences of

  - `&` - literal `&` symbol
  - `[^&]+` - 1 or more symbols other than `&`
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

You need the (arguably poorly named) [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function.

```
// Parse the query string
parse_str("?language=english&test=1", $arr);
```

Now `$arr` will be an associative array, containing the key-values you originally put in the query string:
`array("language" => "english", "test" => "1")`